# Is The Twitter user search rate limit per authorized user, or per API account?

Tags: twitter

I know there is a limit of 60 per hour when doing user search (searching Twitter users by interests, keywords, etc), but is this on a per OAuth token basis or per API account?

I've seen threads like this: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2418 but given that the API rules have changed, am wondering what is the case right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do an Oauth, you get to use 180 calls/hour according to the new API limits. Heres the documentation:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search

Edit: This is per OAuth token. Keep in mind that if you try to bypass the limit by cycling through several Oauth tokens, twitter may block your ip address.

Comment: Why would Twitter block me if I try to do that? Isn't that the point of asking twitter users to authorize you and get an OAuth token for each user?

Comment: @Hisoka did you get answer for your question ? i am searching for the samething , is it ok to use different OAuth token for the users authorized my app to use it ?!